# Manually building assets - DXA 1.7

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7

We're looking to manually build our assets for HTML design and include them in our Java application rather than have them built from the CMS.  I have followed the instructions as per:
https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/dxa-html-design-decisions

And get as for as the application recognising the new version number in `/system/assets/version.json`
I'll increment, and the front end version does increment when including `${markup.versionedContent('/assets/css/main.css')}` in my view

However, I am stuck on the application actually recognising any new assets.  I have added `/src/main/webapp/system/assets/css/myowncss.css` within the app, but if I try to reference that through a browser, I get a blank page (rather than a 404 or 500).  Where am I going wrong?

We are developing with dxa-web-application-java 1.7

Thanks,

Craig.

Answer (score 1):

Till Dxa 1.5, it was monolithic code for the html design process, all code under publishHtmlDesign.cs covering few methods.

i had to update/comment few lines of code to remove DXA OOTB approach.

i have created a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/RAJMITTAL/393f58efd076b9f23e36ad2ada49b000) for working code.

Comment: Thanks Raj but we're not building in .NET

Comment: its C# tbb, are you using java in Tbb?

Comment: Hi Raj - yep, we're using Java

Answer (score 0):

DXA by default tries to find it in the content delivery (in our case in the database table) as you are trying to load the css from `/webapp/system/assets/css/` location.

Try to use a different location, say (`/content/styles/style.css`) it should work fine while loading from the browser

Comment: Thanks Rajesh but I don't think that is quite what I'm after.  In the link above it describes in 4 steps how to remove the HTML design build process from the CMS, and I seem to be getting stuck on step 3:

_3. deploy your CSS, fonts and JavaScript files to the to the /system/assets folder (as part of the deploy of the web application with its views)_

If I add the file in the folder structure directly in, say, Eclipse, it doesn't seem to work. I only mention the browser because you can see /system/assets/main.css in a browser if you build HTML assets through the CMS.